# How to restart App without using Refresh and ReCreate for Android app?

Tags: java, android

In my app i've got a sign-in & sign-up section, which when user sign-up app will save his number into database then in main app will use that phone to get information of user from server. my problem is that when i hit sign-out button app will do it, but problem is still cart and other parts which need sign-in, still working, and when i restart app it will sign-out user completely and make user to sing-in again to access. i've used `recreate & finish` and it's not working. here's the code for check if user exist, which base of this make app to get user info :

```
private void checkSessionLogin() {

    UserDbHelper userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase database = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = userDbHelper.readPhone(database);


    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        PhoneNmber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDatabaseUser.UserEntry.PHONE));

    }

    if ((AtlasPref.getInt("user_id",1) == 1)){


        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        //Check exists user on Serve (MySQL)
        mService.checkExistsUser(PhoneNmber)
            .enqueue(new Callback<CheckUserResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Response<CheckUserResponse> response) {
                    CheckUserResponse userResponse = response.body();
                    if (userResponse.isExists())
                    {
                        //Request information of current user
                        mService.getUserInformation(PhoneNmber)
                                .enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                                        Common.currentUser = response.body();
                                        if (Common.currentUser != null) {
                                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                                            updateTokenToServer();

                                            //Set Info
                                            txt_name.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
                                            txt_phone.setText(Common.currentUser.getPhone());
                                            hideItem();
                                            //Set Avatar
                                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Common.currentUser.getAvatarUrl())) {
                                                Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                                                        .load(new StringBuilder(Common.BASE_URL)
                                                                .append("user_avatar/")
                                                                .append(Common.currentUser.getAvatarUrl()).toString())
                                                        .into(img_avatar);
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                        Log.d("ERROR",t.getMessage());

                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
}
else if ((AtlasPref.getInt("user_id",0) == 0))

    {
        showItem();

        txt_name.setText("Name");
        txt_phone.setText("Number");
    }
    else
    {

        showItem();

        txt_name.setText("Name");
        txt_phone.setText("Number");
    }

}
```

Sign-out button :

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                UserDbHelper userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase database = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                userDbHelper.deleteContact(PhoneNmber,database);
                userDbHelper.close();

                //Clear All Activity
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=AtlasPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("user_id",0);

                editor.commit();
                // first- i've tried this without 2nd, 3rd
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                // 2nd - I've tried this without 1st, 3rd
                recreate();
                // 3rd - I've tried this without 2nd, 3rd
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for response.

The solution worked for me was using

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

After user signout  restart the entire application from the beginning.

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

here you have to clear your sharedpreference properly

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = AtlasPref.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
finish();
```

Comment: i should terminate app from recent task button, to do it, now i want to do it with that button in app. i mean only when i've use recent task button to close app, it will sign-out user.

Comment: Still same, as i explained top. user sign-in data will store to get user information. cart and favorite work if user is signed-in. now when user sign-out, still cart and favorite work until the i close app from recent task button. those activities won't do any react to sign-out button until i close app from recent app button.

Comment: clear your SharedPreferences properly after sign out

Comment: well it didn't worked... i guess problem is i should make common.currentUser == null; ...

Comment: i've did most of this base of a tutorial, this is the part that i don't really know how to make it equal null.

Answer (score 1):

I make it a library here

https://github.com/ksc91u/apprestart

1. Follow directions here to add jitpack: https://jitpack.io/#ksc91u/apprestart
2. In your Application.onCreate()

   `override fun onCreate() {
       super.onCreate()
       AppPhoenix.init(this)
   }`
3. In your activity, where 'this' is the activity

   `AppPhoenix.getInstance().restart(this)`

Comment: is this with kotlin? can i use it for my project which it's not with kotlin?

Comment: I wrote in kotlin. You can write something similar in Java too.

Comment: Updated answer, you can use library on jitpack

Comment: well i've fixed this just right now with `system.exit(0);` and it's working fine.